# How to I write a unit test for a component with a router.events subscriptin?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, angular2-routing, subscription

I have a component that subscribes to the router events in order to close the sidebar when a link is clicked

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
      this.closeNav();
    });
  }
```

All the tests in the spec file are failing with the following error

```
Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
```

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: show the constructor

Comment: constructor(private router:Router) {}